# When will a kube object have more than one ownerReferences

Tags: kubernetes

When a kubernetes object has parent objects, it is mentioned under "ownerReferences".  For example when i printed a pod spec in yaml format, i see ownerReferences mentioned as follows:

```
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: statefuleset-name
    uid: <uuid>
....
```

I see that ownerReferences is a list.  Does anyone know when the ownerReferences will have more than one entries.  I am not able to imagine a object having more than one owner.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly it is possible in some circumstances.

In [this blog](https://medium.com/@bharatnc/kubernetes-garbage-collection-781223f03c17) you can see an example of multiple `ownerReferences`. The blog explains garbage collection in K8s and shows that **Multiple ownerReferences are possible**:

> Yes, you heard that right, now postgres-namespace can be owned by more
>   than one database object.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own use-case and respective CRDs and there can be a requirement of associating an object with multiple owners.

Just taking a very basic example, consider there is a School, with multiple teachers and multiple students, if all 3 are different CRDs then the student may have OwnerReference of kind `School` with the school name and OwnerReference of kind `Teacher` with teacher name.

By the way, [cluster-api](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cluster-api) uses multiple ownerReferences in few of it's CRDs.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on this, the owner refs are used for two scenarios:

1. garbage collection
2. adoption (e.g. of existing pods into a deployment based on a selector)

Garbage collection works in a uniform way; the object is a candidate after ALL owners are deleted.

The `controller` field was added later to support scenario (2).